# Very stupid question about curvature of a circle

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, curves

It is a well-known fact that curvature of a circle with radius $R$ is equal to $\frac{1}{R}$. But if I write parameterization like $\gamma=(R\cos\frac{\tau}{R},R\sin\frac{\tau}{R})$ (because it must be a natural parametrization with $\vert \frac{d\gamma}{d\tau}\vert=1$) and then differentiate it  twice I obtain $\frac{d^2\gamma}{d\tau^2}=(-\frac{1}{R}\cos\frac{\tau}{R},-\frac{1}{R}\sin\frac{\tau}{R})$ which gives $k=\vert \frac{d^2\gamma}{d\tau^2} \vert = \frac{\sqrt2}{R}$. What am I missing?..

Comment: Where did $\sqrt 2$ came?

Comment: $\cos^2{a}+\sin^2{a}=1$, not 2.

Comment: They say there are no stupid questions, only stupid answers.

Comment: Oh, sorry!.. Surely yes! I did a very stupid mistake: $\vert \frac{d^2\gamma}{d\tau^2} \vert= \sqrt{\frac{1}{R^2}(\cos^2\frac{\tau}{R}+\sin^2\frac{\tau}{R})} = \frac{1}{R}$, so everything is fine.

Comment: I've seen the same mistake made many times by students rushing through computations ...

Comment: The best part of this question was stopping to think at the end and knowing you'd made a mistake somewhere. You  can answer your own question and highlight your error for others to learn from.